# Why Python builtin sum() function does not support strings?

Tags: python, sum, reduce

The `sum()` function work only with numbers, not strings.

```
  int_lst = [1, 2]
  sum(int_lst)
=> 3

   str_lst = ['a', 'b']
   sum(str_lst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I found this behaviour strange because `sum()` function is just a more pythonic way to do `reduce(lambda i, sum:i+sum)`. And reduce allows me to concatenate strings, but `sum()` doesn't.

[From python documentation for sum()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

> The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not
> allowed to be a string.

**So why?**

OOP teaches us to make polymorphic stuff because it's flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing strings is *very inefficient*; summing strings in a loop requires that a new string is created for each two strings being concatenated, only to be destroyed again when the next string is concatenated with that result.

For example, for summing `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']` you'd create `'foobar'`, then `'foobarbaz'`, then `'foobarbazspam'`, then `'foobarbazspamham'`, then finally `'foobarbazspamhameggs'`, discarding all but the last string object.

You'd use the `str.join()` method instead:

```
''.join(str_list)
```

which creates *one* new string and copies in the contents of the constituent strings.

Note that `sum()` uses a default starting value of `0`, which is why you get your specific exception message:

```
>>> 0 + ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You can give `sum()` a different starting value as the second argument; for strings that'll give you a more meaningful error message:

```
>>> sum(['foo', 'bar'], '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```

The function is otherwise not limited to just numbers; you can use it for any other type that defines `__add__` operations, but you have to specify a sensible start value. You could 'sum' lists, for example:

```
>>> sum([['foo', 'bar'], ['ham', 'spam']], [])
['foo', 'bar', 'ham', 'spam']
```

but note the `[]` value for the second (`start`) argument! This is also just as inefficient as summing strings; the efficient method would be using `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))`.

Comment: `list(chain.from_iterable(l))` would be faster again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: did you time that? Because either way the list is going to be iterated over.

Comment: I have always found it to be faster. On `l = [['foo', 'bar'], ['ham', 'spam']] * 100000` it is  12ms vs 8.3ms.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yeah, just confirmed `from_iterable` is marginally faster.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I used `testdata = [[None] * random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(100)]` and 10k repeats to get 0.15 vs 0.22.

Comment: roughly the same here